# API not returning a value for Email

Tags: c#, google-plus

I downloaded and setup the [example](https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/csharp),I uncommented the following in the code.

```
static public string[] SCOPES = { PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail };
```

It retrieves my name, friend etc but it does not retrieve my email address.

Is anyone able to assist? Possibly i'm looking in the incorrect place.

Comment: have you read google documentation? Usually e-mail is a sensitive information and needs permission to be read. For example when I used facebook API, I had this problem. I believe this is something related to permission

Answer (score 0):

I used tested it using [Try It](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it).  I tested it with all of the different scopes

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login Know your basic profile
> info and list of people in your circles.
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me Know who you are on Google
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email View your email address
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile View basic
> information about your account

It doesn't appear to matter you get back the email in all of the scopes. But what does matter is that the Users email must be set to `public` in the Account.  If its set to anything else, your circles, only you. its not listed.  This appears to be true even when you are trying to see your own information.  (Sending Me)